# Comparing between dates in order to fill the appropriate color

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

using the VBA in excel i have a code that compare the entered dates with the current date and based on the result the system will fill the cell in the right color.

where the code compare in four conditions.
if the entered date minus the current is :

- = 0
- less then 0
- between 1 and 4
- between 4 and 10

using the IF statement but the system give me an error where is the error and how to fix it ?

## code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer


For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'


       If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then Exit Sub

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) < 0 Then
              Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) = 0 Then
             Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) > 1 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) < 4 Then
              Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbBlue

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) > 4 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) < 10 Then
               Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed


End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use VBA at all? Conditional formatting can do this sort of thing. In any event, if you have an error -- please be more specific. What line is throwing the error? What error message?

Comment: i tried using conditional formating but it did not work as i want

Answer (score 1):

put `Exit Sub` in next row. Or even better, remove that line of code to allow processing all rows, like...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer


For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'


       If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then


       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) < 0 Then
              Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) = 0 Then
             Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 1 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 4 Then
       Debug.Print VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()
              Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbBlue

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) > 4 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) < 10 Then
       Debug.Print VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()
               Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed

       Else
       Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbWhite
       End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: you solved my error thank you.
but now i have a problem  either if the result is between 1 and 4 or more the color will be blue.

Comment: I adjusted my answer, now you should get all colors right. In case date difference is more than 10 days, cell color will turn to white...